Latest artifact bar file from azure devops artifactory
Problem statement: I want to fetch the latest artifact bar url from azure artifactory, to deploy it to the openshift container platform. I am using this ({organization_url}/{project_name}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=7.1-preview.7) to fetch the buildid and through buildid I am able to fetch the bar url from Azure artifacts, but here the problem is ({organization_url}/{project_name}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=7.1-preview.7) this api wont fetch the buildid which ran 2 months ago. When the pipeline rans after the two months, it will ignore the bar url and it wont get deployed.
Now I need help to get the latest bar url directly without using build id, example if my appplicationname and artifact name is ace.bar, using this bar name it should get the latest version of the bar. and construct the barurl.


Could you please clarify what exactly you mean by "artifact bar file"? Is it an artifact? It would be better to share a sample "bar url " to help us understand your question. 2. "this api wont fetch the buildid which ran 2 months ago" - Based on my test, this API can return builds from two months ago, or even two years ago. Please check in the UI whether your target build still exists. If it can no longer be found in the UI, the API will not return relevant information.


Hi, Thank you for your response. bar file is artifact which is built from a IBM ACE application. so now I want to fetch the latest bar artifacts URL from the azure artifacts repository. suggest me best way...

I understand that you want to fetch the latest bar artifacts URL. The artifacts published by the pipeline are associated with each build, so to obtain the URL of the artifact, the build id is required. To give you a better suggestion, I want to know these: 1. Please check in the UI whether your target build still exists. If your target build has been deleted, the artifact published by this build will also be deleted. 2. You said you want to deploy your latest artifact to the openshift container platform, how did you deploy it? Using the Azure DevOps pipeline or something else?

If you are using Azure DevOps pipeline for deployment, you can use DownloadBuildArtifacts@1 task to download the latest artifact. If you want to download the artifact to somewhere else via the REST API, we need to get the build id.


in the UI I target build exist and can view them in the artifacts too. 2. I am using azure devops pipeline to deploy to OCP using HELM chart(where we are maintain the templates and call them through values.yaml). to give more information (I am using this restapi - ({organization_url}/{project_name}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=7.1-preview.7)  )
to fetch all the build, but this api is giving count 1000 , in which latest two month buildid are not visible.  can you please elaborate how can I fetch the url from  DownloadBuildArtifacts@1 task?


Hi @vamshi, to get the URL of your target artifact, you can add a definitions filter in the request to list builds only of your target pipeline. About using DownloadBuildArtifacts@1 task to download the latest artifact, I have explained it in detail in the answer below. You can check it.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.


this api is giving count 1000

This REST API has a limit of 1000 builds. To get the URL of your target artifact, you can add a definitions filter in the request to list builds only of your target pipeline.
 GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?definitions={definitions}&api-version=7.1-preview.7

definitions: A comma-delimited list of definition IDs. If specified, filters to builds for these definitions.


You can get the definition ID of your target pipeline from the UI. Go to your target pipeline, you can see the definition id as shown below. For this example, the request is https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?definitions=411&api-version=7.1-preview.7



You can also get the definition id from REST API Pipelines - List.

For my suggestion "use DownloadBuildArtifacts@1 task to download the latest artifact" mentioned in the comment above, this task will not return the URL of the artifact directly, it will download your target artifact into the working directory of your deployment pipeline. Then you can deploy it directly to your platform. Therefore, you don't need to download artifacts using the REST API.
YAML:
- task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    buildType: 'specific'
    project: '{the project holding your target pipeline}'
    pipeline: '{your target pipeline}'
    buildVersionToDownload: 'latest'
    downloadType: 'single'
    downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'

Classic:


Hi Ziyang, thank you for responding in elaborate way. the build artifacts task I am using it in on-prem setup and that doesn't work in my present case. 2. (https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?definitions=411&api-version=7.1-preview.7) i tried this api, its returning all the json file with all the build. how can I get the url which download the artifacts. MY case is below yaml for reference.

I am using CRD based approach, which contain  multiple artifacts url and  deploy it to  integration server, (https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/app-connect/container?topic=resources-integration-server-reference#install) for your reference.

According to your original description "I am using this ({organization_url}/{project_name}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=7.1-preview.7) to fetch the buildid and through buildid I am able to fetch the bar url from Azure artifacts", if you get the buildid, you will be able to fetch the bar url. So I think the issue is to help you get the buildid. "its returning all the json file with all the build" - The definitions is just to filter all the builds of one pipeline and it returns the same info as you did before. You should be able to get the buildid from the response.

Hi @vamshi, it's my pleasure. Do you need any other help regarding this question?

No thank you @ziyang.

Hi @vamshi, thanks for your update. It's great to know you don't have any issue regarding this question. To help others who have the similar question with you know this answer more clearly, it would be better if you could accept my answer according to How does accepting an answer work. Thanks!
